# Undefined reference to function when included w/ header

Tags: c, makefile

I've been confused as to why this specific error is coming up.
The function being called looks the same so I don't think it is a type/case-sensitive error. I've included my makefile, the header in question, and the code snippet of the C file using the header + calling the function.

If anything else would be relevant I could supply it.
Thanks to anyone that helps!

game_state.h

```
#ifndef GAME_STATE_H
#define GAME_STATE_H

typedef struct Game_Condition_struct {
    bool vertical_win;
    bool down_diag_win;
    bool up_diag_win;
    char* player_char;
} GAME;

void Game_Over(BOARD* board);
void Win_Check(BOARD* board, GAME* game_condition);

#endif
```

moves.c snippet

```
#include "game_state.h"
... // other code above
else {
        Make_Move(board, user_move, player_char);
        Print_Board(board);
        // IF-ELSE to change the player turn
        if (*player_char == 'X') {
            *player_char = 'O';
        }
        else {
            *player_char = 'X';
        }
        Game_Over(board);
}
```

game_state.c

```
void Game_Over(BOARD* board) {
     GAME game_condition;
     Win_Check(board, &game_condition);
}
```

makefile

```
connectn.out: board.o main.o read_args.o moves.o game_state.o
     gcc -g -Wall -o connectn.out board.o main.o read_args.o moves.o

main.o: board.h read_args.h moves.h game_state.h main.c
     gcc -g -Wall -c -o main.o  main.c

board.o: board.h board.c
     gcc -g -Wall -c -o board.o board.c

read_args.o: read_args.h read_args.c
     gcc -g -Wall -c -o read_args.o read_args.c

moves.o: moves.h board.h game_state.h moves.c
     gcc -g -Wall -c -o moves.o moves.c

game_state.o: game_state.h board.h game_state.c
     gcc -g -Wall -c -o game_state.o game_state.c

clean:
     rm *.o *.out
```

The code works as I expect if I don't include the Game_Over(board) call, so I'm confused as to why it's not defined.
BOARD is a struct I made, similar to GAME.

Comment: in the game condition struct, I wonder why there is no horizontal_win entry.

Comment: I had forgotten that particular win condition, but there is one now:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't link `game_state.o` into `connectn.out`. Add `game_state.o` to the end of the 2nd line of Makefile.

Comment: I have it at the end, after moves.o, is that not linking?

Genuinely curious as to what you mean!

Comment: Oh I see you what you mean now, in the actual compile command; Let me try it

Comment: I knew it was something so simple, thanks very much!

Comment: To be clear, that's the _link_ command where it's missing.  Compilation turns a source file into an object file (`.o`).  Linking turns object files into a program (`connectn.out`) (or a shared library, but you're not building one of those).